# Не могу понять блок кода в реализации LinkedList

Tags: java

Дана реализация связанного списка:

```
class Link {
    public int data1;
    public double data2;
    public Link nextLink;

    //Link constructor
    public Link(int d1, double d2) {
        data1 = d1;
        data2 = d2;
    }

    //Print Link data
    public void printLink() {
        System.out.print("{" + data1 + ", " + data2 + "} ");
    }
}

class LinkList {
    private Link first;

    //LinkList constructor
    public LinkList() {
        first = null;
    }

    //Returns true if list is empty
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return first == null;
    }

    //Inserts a new Link at the first of the list
    public void insert(int d1, double d2) {
        Link link = new Link(d1, d2);
        link.nextLink = first;
        first = link;
    }

    //Deletes the link at the first of the list
    public Link delete() {
        Link temp = first;
        if(first == null){
            return null;
            //throw new NoSuchElementException(); // this is the better way.
        }
        first = first.nextLink;
        return temp;
    }

    //Prints list data
    public void printList() {
        Link currentLink = first;
        System.out.print("List: ");
        while(currentLink != null) {
            currentLink.printLink();
            currentLink = currentLink.nextLink;
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}

class LinkListTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkList list = new LinkList();

        list.insert(1, 1.01);
        list.insert(2, 2.02);
        list.insert(3, 3.03);
        list.insert(4, 4.04);
        list.insert(5, 5.05);

        list.printList();



    }
}
```

Не могу понять метод

```
public void insert(int d1, double d2) {
        Link link = new Link(d1, d2);
        link.nextLink = first;
        first = link;
    }
```

И его вызов list.insert В теле метода сохраняется ссылка на вновь созданный объект в first.
При повторном вызове метода ссылка переписывается.
Где сохраняется предыдущий элемент?

Comment: Ссылка на предыдущий элемент сохраняется в текущем элементе (голове списка) - идет вставка в начало списка. Т.е. новый элемент становится головой списка - а все что было ранее - хвостом.

Answer (score 0):

Можно разобрать этот пример более детально, чтобы понять, что происходит, например, так

```
1) LinkList list = new LinkList();
```

Выделили место под LinkList и внутри объекта у нас объявляются поля
`private Link first;`

```
2) list.insert(1, 1.01);
```

Здесь происходит

```
2.1)    Link link = new Link(d1, d2);
2.2)    link.nextLink = first;
2.3)    first = link;
```

2.1 - создание нового объекта `Link`
Также внутри этого объекта создаются поля
`public int data1;
 public double data2;
 public Link nextLink;`
И сразу происходит заполнение `data1,data2` параметрами, которые были переданы, в данном случае 1 и 1.01 соответственно.

2.2 - ссылку от нашего проинициализированнового объекта мы заносим в `nextLink`, который был объявлен в 2.1

2.3 - сохраняем ссылку на текущий объект `link` в `first`, который был объявлен в пункте 1.

В итоге, у нас получается, что новый занесенный элемент это всегда первый, а тот, что был до этого первым, он становится следующим.

Следовательно, вот что тут будет

```
    LinkList list = new LinkList(); //first ==null, next - не определен

    list.insert(1, 1.01);  //first == new Link(1, 1.01), next == null
    list.insert(2, 2.02);  //first == new Link(2, 2.02), next == new Link(1, 1.01)
    list.insert(3, 3.03);  //...
    list.insert(4, 4.04);  //...
    list.insert(5, 5.05);  //first == new Link(5, 5.05), next == new Link(4, 4.04)
```

**P.S** Если я где-то допустил ошибку, просьба меня поправить.

Comment: Спасибо за столь подробный ответ.
То есть на предыдущий объект в куче не уничтожается сборщиком, потому что на него указывает nextLink текущего объекта?

Comment: Пожалуйста. Насколько видно из вашей реализации списка, нет. Также, вы это можете видет, во время запуска вашего приложения. У вас всё выводится в консоль/output